# Dynamically change color of button in list of buttons with flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to dynamically change the color of a button in a list of buttons, meaning that if one of the three buttons is pressed, the other two should change to the default color, With my current setup the button that has been pressed changes colors, but the inactive buttons don't return to the original state, which makes the impression that all buttons are active.

Thanks for your help!

This is the parent `Container` that uses the array to render the buttons:

```
class Categories extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _Categories();
  }
}

class _Categories extends State<Categories> {
  int activeCategory = 0;


  final titles = ["Experiences", "Adventures", "Activities"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: titles.mapIndexed((index, title) => CategoryButton(index, title, activeCategory)).toList()
    );
  }
}
```

This is the button:

```
class CategoryButton extends StatefulWidget {
  CategoryButton(this.currentIndex, this.title, this.activeCategory, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CategoryButton> createState() => _CategoryButtonState();
  int currentIndex, activeCategory;
  final String title;
}

class _CategoryButtonState extends State<CategoryButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          widget.activeCategory = widget.currentIndex;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 38.0,
        width: screenWidth * 0.30,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
          color: Color(widget.activeCategory == widget.currentIndex ? 0xFF63D1D9 : 0x00FFFFFF)
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            widget.title,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Poppins",
              fontSize: 15.6,
              color: Color(0xFF332418)
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to get `ontap` function from the Categories state as parameter.use the `setState` method in there

Answer (score 0):

So basically, I removed the button from its own separate widget and added it to the categories widget. Here is the new code:

```
class Categories extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _Categories();
  }
}

class _Categories extends State<Categories> {
  int activeCategory = 0;

  final titles = ["Experiences", "Adventures", "Activities"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: titles.mapIndexed((index, title) => InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            activeCategory = index;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 38.0,
          width: screenWidth * 0.30,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
            color: Color(activeCategory == index ? 0xFF63D1D9 : 0x00FFFFFF)
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                fontSize: 15.6,
                color: Color(0xFF332418)
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )).toList()
    );
  }
}
```